# How do I ensure that re.findall() stops at the right place?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, findall

Here is the code I have:

```
a='<title>aaa</title><title>aaa2</title><title>aaa3</title>'
import re
re.findall(r'<(title)>(.*)<(/title)>', a)
```

The result is:

```
[('title', 'aaa</title><title>aaa2</title><title>aaa3', '/title')]
```

If I ever designed a crawler to get me titles of web sites, I might end up with something like this rather than a title for the web site.

My question is, how do I limit `findall` to a single `<title></title>`?

Comment: You can use BeautifulSoup to parse HTML instead of Regex

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/193892

Answer (score 13):

Use `re.search` instead of `re.findall` if you only want one match:

```
>>> s = '<title>aaa</title><title>aaa2</title><title>aaa3</title>'
>>> import re
>>> re.search('<title>(.*?)</title>', s).group(1)
'aaa'
```

If you wanted all tags, then you should consider changing it to be non-greedy (ie - `.*?`):

```
print re.findall(r'<title>(.*?)</title>', s)
# ['aaa', 'aaa2', 'aaa3']
```

But really consider using BeautifulSoup or lxml or similar to parse HTML.

Comment: It's true that using regexen to parse HTML or XML is usually a bad idea.

Answer (score 5):

Use a non-greedy search instead:

```
r'<(title)>(.*?)<(/title)>'
```

The question-mark says to match as few characters as possible.  Now your findall() will return each of the results you want.

http://docs.python.org/2/howto/regex.html#greedy-versus-non-greedy

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall(r'<(title)>(.*?)<(/title)>', a)
```

Add a `?` after the `*`, so it will be non-greedy.

Answer (score 1):

It will be much easier using BeautifulSoup module.

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/beautifulsoup4