# Twisted Proxy using TCP reactor works at which level of OSI layer?

Tags: python, python-2.7, twisted, twisted.web

Can anybody say me  at which level of OSI layer
Twisted Proxy using TCP reactor works

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I ensure that re.findall() stops at the right place?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17765805/how-do-i-ensure-that-re-findall-stops-at-the-right-place)

Comment: There isn't a "TCP reactor".